# Nyasam and the appearance of deity

Tags: vishnu, krishna, gods, rama

While reading the Preface of Sharda-tilak tantra, the writer explained some general facts. He while stating the way to do the Nyasam writes:
(I am translating)

> One has to use the Ring finger, middle finger and index finger for gods with three eyes. While if the Deity has two eyes use the index and middle finger.

However until now I have only seen 'Netra-TraYay VauShata' ( नेत्रत्रयाय वौषट्) and never came across any Nyasam involving two eyes like- 'Netra-DwiYay VauShata' (नेत्रद्वयाय वौषट्) **(Example?)**.If I am not wrong then, Vishnu has two eyes, while in SahasraNamam its Netra TraYay. (Even certain stotras involving krishna or Rama as devta, its Netra-TraYa) Does this mean Nyasam and Appearance of deity are not dependent?

**For which deity should the Nyasam involve two eyes? For which It should be three?**

Edit: In [Siddha Lakshmi stotram](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/siddhilakShmIstotram.html),
the Nyasam involves Netra-DwiYay VauShata' (नेत्रद्वयाय वौषट्) however the Dhyanam says the deity has three eyes,

> ...ॐ तं तेजःप्रकाशिनी **नेत्रद्वयाय वौषट्** । ॐ ह्रीं क्लीं श्रीं ब्राह्मीं वैष्णवीं फट्
> ॥ अथ ध्यानम् ॥
> ब्राह्मीं च वैष्णवीं भद्रां षड्भुजां च चतुर्मुखाम् । **त्रिनेत्रां** च त्रिशूलां च पद्मचक्रगदाधराम् ॥ १॥

So why does Naysam involves Netra-DwiYay VauShata' (नेत्रद्वयाय वौषट्) despite of the fact that the Deity has three eyes?

Comment: [This research paper](https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/bitstream/10603/218019/8/08%20chapter%202%20&%203.pdf) states - *"In Vaishnava and
Madhva sampradayas, the two eyes are touched whereas in smarta sampradaya, three points
(two eyes and the center of eyebrows representing the third eye) are touched. This is called
shadanganyasa."*